# Storing an array of floats in RealmSwift

Tags: swift, realm

I need to store an array of floats on one of my objects being persisted. It results in me getting an RLMException for trying to store an NSArray type, which is not supported.

Googling found a thread with someone having a similar issue with an array of strings. The suggested workaround was the create an extra wrapper class, inheriting from Object, for storing the string as a Realm object relationship.

I'm hoping to not have to do a workaround such as this. Is there another way to go about storing an array of floats?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a particularly difficult workaround, is there any reason you're not keen?

Comment: Yeah, its not that its difficult. Just didn't want the extra class if possible since its not really adding anything and is making it so I can't work purely with the desired datatypes.

I'll probably end up writing some extra wrapping functions with get/set to make it less obvious, but curious if there is actually another way since the threads I found were a bit old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no other way yet than the workaround you already found.
We track adding support for arrays of primitives by [issue #1120](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1120).

Retrieving a list of primitives is easily possible though by making use of the KVC-compliance of Realm accessors. If you have a property `@property RLMArray<FloatObject> *numbers;` where `FloatObject` has a property `floatValue` which has the primitive type `float`, you can retrieve an NSArray of NSNumbers by using `[myObject.numbers valueForKey:@"floatValue"]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also thanks for linking to the thread.